# JavaScript - Hangman - Logic Issue

Tags: code.org, app-lab

I'm trying to get my Hangman game to check if the letter is found in the word, but as of now it's checking if that letter is found in every character of the word.  It won't allow me to guess again after the first guess.

```
setScreen("WelcomeScreen");
//variables
var WordArray = ["apple", "word", "quiz"];
var currentWord = ""; 
var wrongCounter = 0;
var bodyPartCounter = 0; 
var Guess = "";
//Welcome Screen Code
onEvent("letsGoBtn", "click", function () {
  setScreen("playingHangmanScreen");
  generateWord(); 
  setUpScreenElements();
});

function generateWord() {
  currentWord = WordArray[randomNumber(0,2)];
  console.log(currentWord);
}
function setUpScreenElements(){
  for (var i = 0; i < currentWord.length; i++) {
    showElement("letterArea" + [i]);
  }
  var showCorrectHint = "hintWord" + currentWord;
  showElement(showCorrectHint);
  console.log(showCorrectHint);
}
//Guessing Code
onEvent("submitBtn", "click", function () {
  Guess = getText("guessInputTxt");
  console.log("The guess for " + currentWord + " is: " + Guess);
  checkGuess();
});

function checkGuess() {
    for (var i = 0; i < currentWord.length; i++) {
      if (Guess == currentWord.charAt([i])) {
        setText("letterArea" + [i], Guess);
        console.log("Correctly guessed letter is: " + currentWord.charAt([i]));
      } 
      else {
        wrongCounter++;
        console.log("wrongCounter for " + currentWord + " is: " + wrongCounter);
        if (wrongCounter == currentWord.length) {
          bodyPartCounter++;
          showElement("wrongGuessImg" + bodyPartCounter);
          setText("livesLeftNumber", (6-bodyPartCounter));
        }
        if (bodyPartCounter === 6) {
          setScreen("gameOverScreen");
        }
      }
    } 
    resetGuessInput();
  }

function resetGuessInput () {
  setText("guessInputTxt", " ");
  Guess = " ";
  wrongCounter = 0;
}
//Game Over Screen and Play Again Button
onEvent("playAgainBtn", "click", function () {
  hideElement("hintWord" + currentWord);
  generateWord();
  setUpScreenElements();
  setScreen("playingHangmanScreen");
  for (var i = 0; i <currentWord.length; i++) {
    setText("letterArea" + [i], " ");
  }
  for (var j = 1; j < 7; j++) {
    hideElement("wrongGuessImg" + [j]);
  }
  bodyPartCounter = 0;
  wrongCounter = 0;
  setText("livesLeftNumber", "6");
});
//Victory Screen 
onEvent("goHomeBtn", "click", function() {
  setScreen("WelcomeScreen");
});
```

I've attached the code, as well as, included the link to see the app in action.

[Here's a link to the app](https://studio.code.org/projects/applab/6Q3akuzqZV6quZrPM4MH0urxUDI_fp4Zuem4dH5JXis)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The checkGuess function needs to first determine where the letter appears in the word (or not), and then update the board one time, instead of updating it for each character:

```
function checkGuess() {
  var foundAtIndex = -1;
  for (var i = 0; i < currentWord.length; i++) {
    if (Guess == currentWord.charAt([i])) {
      foundAtIndex = i;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (foundAtIndex >= 0) {
    setText("letterArea" + [foundAtIndex], Guess);
    // etc...
```

Luckily, Javascript provides a nice [IndexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) function for strings, so you can remove the loop entirely and condense that first part into:

```
var foundAtIndex = currentWord.indexOf(Guess);
```