# How to create a function for a hint button in code.org

Tags: javascript, function, button, code.org

How do I create a function for my hangman game in [code.org](https://code.org/)?

I need to make a **"Hint" button**, so that when I press the button, the hint that goes to the word you're going to guess, gives you a clue.

#### Example

My word is `abandon` and the clue would say following when I click on the "Hint" button:

> To cease to support or look after (someone); desert

I already made the variables for the guess words in the hangman game like:

```js
var words= ["abandon", "above", "about"];
var word = "";
```

Comment: Have another array for definitions who's indexes correlate with `words`

Comment: Without seeing more of your code, it's hard to answer or suggest a solution. Please post either a link to the app/code or the complete code as [example], like done in a similar question: [hangman at code.org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43589790/javascript-hangman-logic-issue).

Answer (score 1):

I made a little mock up of what your describing. Since Code.org is have design and half code, note my design. Your can interact with my design [sample hangman program](https://studio.code.org/projects/applab/38gmbu9k7LCiyPIRALOnHVQgEKVQ1PuPkC7hXmOGc3k).

[image: Basic AppLab screen design with text entry, hint label, and three buttons]

I made a corresponding list `hints`.  I then select a random number and store in `index`.  This tells me which spot in `words` and `hints` to use.

I then implement my three buttons.  The first, `hintBtn`, sets the text of the label, and unhides it (it was hidden as part of *DesignMode*).

The second button, `newWordBtn`, picks a different `index` to use as the answer.  It also makes the hint hidden again (we change the text of the hint label when the user clicks `hintBtn`).

I've left the `guessBtn` for you to fully implement.

```
//Code.org Project: https://studio.code.org/projects/applab/38gmbu9k7LCiyPIRALOnHVQgEKVQ1PuPkC7hXmOGc3k
var words= ["abandon", "above", "apple"];
var hints = ["to be left without warning", "not below", "Washington's fruit"];

var index = randomNumber(0, words.length - 1);

var word = words[index];

onEvent("hintBtn", "click", function( ) {
  //this code will run when "Hint" clicked
  //will grab the hint from the hints list 
  //  based on what spot using right now ('index')
  setProperty("hintText", "text", hints[index]);
  //reveal the hint (want to change the text first)
  setProperty("hintText", "hidden", false);
});

onEvent("newWordBtn", "click", function( ) {
  //change which word spot using
  index = randomNumber(0, words.length - 1); 
  //rehide the hint text
  setProperty("hintText", "hidden", true);
});

onEvent("guessBtn", "click", function( ) {
  //to implement
  console.log(word);
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for that tip, I missed that.  I don't have that ability yet since I don't have enough reputation.  Time to build some reputation!

Comment: Better? I think I have created a more full answer with correct formatting.

Comment: Fabulous: complete code with explaining comments, illustrative image added inline, some human-language as guiding steps. ️ Only the link seems broken and deserves a better name than "here". Give it a name describing its content, e.g. "my example hangman project" or similar